# Points awarded for a user being removed?

Tags: support

[image]I have no idea what this is in relation to or why I got points for it.  Any way to find out who this user is that got removed and why I got points for it?

Comment: Lucky you! I got `-40` for the user being removed. Apparently, he voted four answers down for you and up for me.

Comment: @RonMaupin Oooh. Sorry about that. Which questions was it on?

Comment: That's nothing. I lost over 2K one day when a user was removed. [metase] was ablaze with people losing reputation from all over, and the Moderator's chat was going crazy. I never saw anyone who claimed to lose more than I did from that event.

Comment: @RonMaupin Holy ****! Yeah, that's probably a record for SE.

Comment: I just looked it up. it was `-2040` and `-10` that day, but I did get some positve votes on other things, so the total for the day was `-1980` on May 25 of this year. I get negative numbers from users being removed all the time. There have been a few times where I gained a little, usually just `2`.

Comment: @RonMaupin craziness

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think mods have the 'power' to check this, but most likely this user downvoted some of your questions or answers, and by deleting his account you got these points back.

Comment: Oh. There was an incident with that a while back, where a user downvoted a few of my accepted answers out of rage for me telling them their own answer was irrelevant to a question. Hopefully that's the case.  That was forever ago. If that was it, I'm surprised it took this long.